# Rails scope syntax issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, scope, chartkick

I am trying to define a scope whereby a field in a related object has a value of 1. It seems to throw an error when I do this:

```
scope :in_progress, ->{Submission.where(current_agent.agent_activities.last.Status: 1)}
```

Desired effect is to call all Submissions that have a status of "In progress" which has a hash value of 1.

Error:
SyntaxError (/Users/gbade/Desktop/RoR/Ottom8/app/models/submission.rb:16: syntax error, unexpected ':'
.agent_activities.last.Status: 1)}
                              ^):

Comment: Try to lowercase the word `status` at the end of the scope.

Comment: Have you checked, you are getting value of current_agent inside scope?
As @mu_is_too_short said you must have to provide error message(s). Modify your question so that anybody can understand what specific issue you are facing?

Comment: @muistooshort, my bad, I have updated the post with the error message. That query is supposed to look at the last status of the current agent in my database.